# How do you use a variable to specify the width in ruby's printf method?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use a variable to specify the width in the printf method like so:

```
puts "MAXES #{last_name_max} #{first_name_max} #{email_address_max} #{zipcode_max} #{city_max} #{state_max} #{street_max} #{homephone_max}"
printf "%-#{last_name_max}s %-#{first_name_max}s %-#{email_address_max}s %-#{zipcode_max}s %-#{city_max}s %-#{state_max}s %-#{street_max}s %-#{homephone_max}s\n", 'LAST NAME', 'FIRST NAME', 'EMAIL', 'ZIPCODE', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE'
queue.each do |attendee|
    printf "%-#{last_name_max}s %-#{first_name_max}s %-#{email_address_max}s %-#{zipcode_max}s %-#{city_max}s %-#{state_max}s %-#{street_max}s %-#{homephone_max}s\n", attendee[:last_name], attendee[:first_name], attendee[:email_address], attendee[:zipcode], attendee[:city], attendee[:state], attendee[:street], attendee[:homephone]
end
```

I've been googling around and playing with irb, and I can't figure out what's wrong. This is the output I get:

```
Enter command: queue print
MAXES 7 6 33 5 11 2 18 12
LAST NAME FIRST NAME EMAIL                             ZIPCODE CITY        STATE ADDRESS            PHONE       
Hasegan Audrey ffbbieucf@jumpstartlab.com        95667 Placerville CA 1570 Old Ranch Rd. 530-919-3000
Zielke  Eli    jbrabeth.buckley@jumpstartlab.com 92037 La Jolla    CA 3024 Cranbrook Ct  858 405 3000
Tippit  Meggie dgsanshamel@jumpstartlab.com      94611 Piedmont    CA 28 Olive Ave.      510 282 4000
Enter command: q
```

In irb, `printf("%-#{width}s", "ad")` works, so I think that you could interpolate variables in `printf`. I printed out the variables I'm using in the line before, so they should be correct. And when I use numbers instead of the variables - `printf "%-20s %-20s...` - it works. I don't know what else could be wrong.

This is my full code:

```
require 'CSV'

puts 'Welcome to Event Reporter!'
print 'Enter command: '
command = gets.chomp

def clean(attribute, type)
    if (type == 'regdate')
    elsif (type == 'first_name')
    elsif (type == 'last_name')
    elsif (type == 'email_address')
    elsif (type == 'homephone')
        homephone = attribute
        homephone = homephone.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '')
        if (homephone.length < 10)
            homephone = '0000000000'
        elsif (homephone.length == 11)
            if (homephone[0] == '1')
                homephone[0] = ''
            else
                homephone = '0000000000'
            end
        elsif (homephone.length > 11)
            homephone = '0000000000'
        end
        return homephone
    elsif (type == 'street')
    elsif (type == 'city')
    elsif (type == 'state')
    elsif (type == 'zipcode')
        zipcode = attribute.to_s.rjust(5, "0")[0..4]
        return zipcode
    end
    return attribute
end

queue = []
while (command != 'q') do
    command = command.split
    if (command[0] == 'load')
        command[1] ? filename = command[1] : filename = 'event_attendees.csv'
        attendees = CSV.open filename, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
        puts "Loaded #{filename}"
    elsif (command[0] == 'find')
        attribute = command[1]
        criteria = command[2]
        attendees.rewind
        attendees.each do |attendee|
            attendee_attribute = clean(attendee[attribute.to_sym], attribute)
            queue << attendee if criteria.to_s.downcase.strip == attendee_attribute.to_s.downcase.strip
        end
    elsif (command[0] == 'queue')
        if command[1] == 'count'
            puts "Count: #{queue.length}"
        elsif command[1] == 'clear'
            queue = []
            puts 'Queue cleared.'
        elsif (command[1] == 'print')
            queue.to_a.sort_by! {|obj| obj[command[3]]} if command[2] == 'by'
            last_name_max, first_name_max, email_address_max, zipcode_max, city_max, state_max, street_max, homephone_max = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            queue.each do |attendee|
                last_name_max = attendee[:last_name].length if attendee[:last_name].length > last_name_max.to_i
                first_name_max = attendee[:first_name].length if attendee[:first_name].length > first_name_max.to_i
                email_address_max = attendee[:email_address].length if attendee[:email_address].length > email_address_max.to_i
                zipcode_max = attendee[:zipcode].length if attendee[:zipcode].length > zipcode_max.to_i
                city_max = attendee[:city].length if attendee[:city].length > city_max.to_i
                state_max = attendee[:state].length if attendee[:state].length > state_max.to_i
                street_max = attendee[:street].length if attendee[:street].length > street_max.to_i
                homephone_max = attendee[:homephone].length if attendee[:homephone].length > homephone_max.to_i
            end
            puts "MAXES #{last_name_max} #{first_name_max} #{email_address_max} #{zipcode_max} #{city_max} #{state_max} #{street_max} #{homephone_max}"
            printf "%-#{last_name_max}s %-#{first_name_max}s %-#{email_address_max}s %-#{zipcode_max}s %-#{city_max}s %-#{state_max}s %-#{street_max}s %-#{homephone_max}s\n", 'LAST NAME', 'FIRST NAME', 'EMAIL', 'ZIPCODE', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE'
            queue.each do |attendee|
                printf "%-#{last_name_max}s %-#{first_name_max}s %-#{email_address_max}s %-#{zipcode_max}s %-#{city_max}s %-#{state_max}s %-#{street_max}s %-#{homephone_max}s\n", attendee[:last_name], attendee[:first_name], attendee[:email_address], attendee[:zipcode], attendee[:city], attendee[:state], attendee[:street], attendee[:homephone]
            end
        elsif (command[1] == 'save')
            output_file = CSV.open(command[3], 'w')
            output_file << ['last_name', 'first_name', 'email_address', 'zipcode', 'city', 'state', 'street', 'homephone']
            queue.each do |attendee|
                output_file << [attendee[:last_name], attendee[:first_name], attendee[:email_address], attendee[:zipcode], attendee[:city], attendee[:state], attendee[:street], attendee[:homephone]]
            end
        end
    elsif (command[0] == 'help')
        puts "load <filename.csv>\nqueue count\nqueue clear\nqueue print\nqueue print by <attribute>\nqueue save to <filename.csv>\nfind <attribute> <criteria>" if !command[1]
        puts 'Loads <filename.csv> (event_attendees.csv if not specified)' if command[1] == 'load'
        if (command[1] == 'queue')
            puts 'The cumulative number of attendees who match the criteria searched for.' if command[2] == 'count'
            puts 'Clears the queue of matched attendees.' if command[2] == 'clear'
            puts 'Prints out a table of the matched attendees.' if command[2] == 'print' && !command[3]
            puts 'Prints out a table of the matched attendees sorted by <attribute>' if command[2] == 'print' && command[3] == 'by'
            puts 'Saves the queue to the file.' if command[2] == 'save'
        end
        puts 'Adds matches to the queue' if command[1] == 'find'
    end
    print 'Enter command: '
    command = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: Read: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing the max length of a field, you didn't count the header in.

```
puts "MAXES #{last_name_max} #{first_name_max}"
#=> 7 6

"LAST NAME" => length 9
"FIRST NAME" => length 10
```

`printf "%-#d"` won't truncate the output to the width as specified in `#`. The first two field overflows, and the following fields moved further as expected.

Comment: I initialized the `*_max` variables to be the length of the headers, and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamZerner There're [`String#ljust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-ljust), `String#center`, `String#rjust` methods, which you may find helpful.